# dynamically assign with jquery css top and left for an image thumb

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have a list of images displayed like this:

```
<div id="imgContainer">
    <ul id="thumbs">
        <li class="trns">
            <a class="magnify" href='/uploads/{{ item.pic1 }}' target="_blank"><img class="thumb" src='/uploads/{{ item.pic1 }}'/></a>
        </li>
        <li class="trns">
            <a class="magnify" href='/uploads/{{ item.pic2 }}' target="_blank"><img class="thumb" src='/uploads/{{ item.pic2 }}'/></a>
        </li>
        <li class="trns">
            <a class="magnify" href='/uploads/{{ item.pic3}}' target="_blank"><img class="thumb" src='/uploads/{{ item.pic3 }}'/></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

i want to dynamically assign minus top and left values to half of the height and width, respectively so my thumbs will contain exactly the middle of the image

something like this (of course it doesnt work)

```
$("#imgContainer").find("img.thumb").css({"top":"-"+this.height/2,"left":"-"+this.width/2"});
```

how can i do that?

thanks

---

Comment: You can add the solution you came up with as an answer and accept it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i ended up using this, it works

```
$("#imgContainer").find("img.thumb").each(function(){
    var mtop = $(this).height()/2*-1;
    var mleft = $(this).width()/2*-1;
    $(this).css({"top":mtop,"left":mleft});
});
```

later edit: it works in all browsers, i had some ajax going on and it confused me a bit

Answer (score 0):

`top` and `left` properties can affect only positioned element, so position of your images should be `relative` (or `absolute` inside a `relative` positioned parent).

anyway if all thumbnails have the same (known) size you could use [`clip()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/clip) only using css

about you code, you should write

```
$("#imgContainer").find("img.thumb").css({
   top : "-"+this.height/2 + 'px' , // note (+'px')
   left: "-"+this.width/2 + 'px' 
});
```

Comment: yes, the imgs are absolute positioned ... the size is not known, thats why i want to dynamically calculate the two values, otherwise i would have hardcoded the values in the css file ...

Comment: it doesnt work, i just tried it .. i updated my question, with my answer :) thanks for the time tho

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$("#imgContainer ul li a img").css({
    top  : "-" + this.height/2,
    left : "-" + this.width/2
});
```